# Strange behavior with arabluatex

Tags: overleaf, arabluatex

I used  arabluatex to produce  arabic text.

I get this in overleaf and in my PC (windows 8.1 MiKTeX 2.9) :

[image]

[image]

Any advice ?

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]

\begin{document}
text before...
\begin{arab}[fullvoc]
\arbcolor[red]{al-_tuqUbu 'l-sawdA'u} fI 'l-fIzyA'i.
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `Overleaf`, `Papeeria`, `LaTeXBase` have not loaded automatically: `! LaTeX Error: File arabluatex.sty not found`.

Comment: Overleaf uses TeX Live 2017, which has an old version of `arabluatex` where `\arbcolor` is not defined. The support team of Overleaf wrote me “we do plan to upgrade to TeX Live 2018 some time this year”. Too bad.

Comment: To workaround the outdated package version on overleaf, you could manually upload all the required files to your project folder. The readme from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/latex/arabluatex contains a list of the necessary steps for manual installation

Comment: @egreg's comment should be turned into an answer.  That said, uploading the files to overleaf as explained by @samcarter will get you out of trouble.  But why not just use the release of `arabluatex` provided by MiKTeX?

Comment: @samcarter Not sure this really helps: there have been several updates of the LuaLaTeX font loader in the meantime and also several updates of LuaTeX itself.

Comment: @egreg If one uploads enough files to overleaf it works* :) https://www.overleaf.com/read/mtgktdqdjhcx (will be a nightmare to keep updated...) [* with "works" I mean it compiles, no idea if the output makes sense or not]

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. That's what I have done for other projects ! @samcarter I agree.

Comment: @Haouam It would be great if you write an answer then accept it to help decrease the number of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

**BACKGROUND:**

> Overleaf tracks the stable Ubuntu releases of TeXLive, and they would usually keep more up to date with with these releases, but due to the merger of Overleaf and ShareLaTeX over the past year they have had to delay the upgrade of the compiler image. Currently, TeXLive 2017 is run on all newly created projects (existing projects use the compiler image from their time of creation to prevent conflicts), and they will be introducing TeXLive 2018 in the coming weeks. **(last updated 15th Aug 2019)**

**SOLUTION (WORK-AROUND):**

1. Download the following files from the required package for `arabluatex` from the TeX Live Development Sources ([link](http://www.tug.org/texlive///devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/arabluatex/)):

   - `arabluatex-patch.sty`
   - `arabluatex.lua`
   - `arabluatex.sty`
   - `arabluatex_fullvoc.lua`
   - `arabluatex_novoc.lua`
   - `arabluatex_trans.lua`
   - `arabluatex_voc.lua`
2. Some additional updated dependencies are required (visible by looking at the error log). Download the following files from the Tex Live Development Sources:

   - `expl3.sty`
   - `expl3-code.tex`
   - `fontspec-luatex.sty`
   - `l3backend-pdfmode.def`
   - `xparse.sty`
3. Upload all files to the root directory at your Overleaf project, run your MWE and you're all done!

[image]

*PS. This solution is a work-around and should only be used until Overleaf update to TeXLive 2018.*